# how to create a table in react solution/package to lookup for string value reference with a number?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

we are working on an SPFX webpart, that webpart will pull/Get the SharePoint web lists along with list template(base template).
We can able to get lists and list template, but issue is list template returns base template number like 100, 1001, 1002 etc.. we know that **100=Generic list, 101=Document library** template etc.. but we want to create a internal table in the solution it self to lookup from this table/TS /JSON etc any file..

please look at the out put how we are getting

| List Name | List type |
| --- | --- |
| List | 100 |
| Document | 101 |

this is how its getting our put but we want to create a table with in solution to lookup when list type value =100 then Generic list, 101=Document list etc..

**Expected output** is

| List Name | List type |
| --- | --- |
| List | Genaric list |
| Document | Document list |

Please find the list of TSX file code what we are using to get and display data.

```
export interface IGetSpListsState{
  sitecontents: [{"Title":"","BaseTemplate":""}]
}
export default class GetSpLists extends React.Component<IGetSpListsProps, IGetSpListsState> {
    static siteurl:string =""; //static member variable
    public constructor (props :IGetSpListsProps, state:IGetSpListsState ){
     super(props);
     this.state={sitecontents: [{"Title":"","BaseTemplate":""}]};
      GetSpLists.siteurl=this.props.websiteUrl;
    }
    
    public componentDidMount() {
      let reactcontexthandiler= this;
      //let reactcontexttemplate=this;
      jquery.ajax({
        url: `${GetSpLists.siteurl}/_api/web/lists?select=Title,Basetemplate&$filter=Hidden eq false`,
        type:"GET",
         headers:{'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose;'},
         success : function (resultData){
          reactcontexthandiler.setState({sitecontents: resultData.d.results});
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorthrown){
          }
        });}
    
// this is main part which we need to display
    public render(): React.ReactElement<IGetSpListsProps> {
    return (
    <div>
    <ol>
    {
    this.state.sitecontents.map(function(mylists,mylistitemkey){
    return(
    <li>
      <span>{mylists.Title}</span>
      <span>{mylists.BaseTemplate}</span>//if there is any way to use here if else if to hard code    the values suggest me with sample piece of code
      </li>);
      })
    }</ol></div>
      );
  }
}
```

Please assist me with clear steps like how can add in the component folder/ how to create table/json values and refer in to TSX file and finally how can lookup the table values.
Or
How can we use If.. else if.. condition please assist me.

**your reply is really appreciate**